# Getting "Compiled with problems" when I start react server

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi Guys am trying to upgrade from React 16 to 18 and am using material ui 4.11 for now and later I'll be upgrading it to V5. but while upgrading React and when I start using `npm start` am getting these below errors.
Can someone help me out?
[image]

Comment: please add errors as text instead of image

Comment: 1) Make sure that all of your dependencies are up-to-date and compatible with React 18. Some older dependencies may cause compatibility issues.  2) Make sure that you're using a version of Material UI that is compatible with React 18. You mentioned that you're using Material UI 4.11 and plan to upgrade to version 5 later. Make sure to review the Material UI documentation to ensure compatibility with React 18.

Answer (score 0):

Material UI v5 is the only version that fully supports React 18, so you'll need to update to mui 5  .

install mui 5 with :  `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`